# javascript scoping? - jquery plugin countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

Hi I am having a problem where scoping seems to be lost. What I am doing wrong?

Suppose the logic is that 1 second is decreased from every counter and not from the last counter only.
What I am doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $.fn.extend({

                countdown: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    daysSelector : 'span.days',
                    hoursSelector : 'span.hours',
                    minutesSelector : 'span.minutes',
                    secondsSelector : 'span.seconds'
                }

                var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
                var _this  = $(this);

                tick =  function()
                {
                    var days = _this.find(options.daysSelector);
                    var hours = _this.find(options.hoursSelector);
                    var minutes = _this.find(options.minutesSelector);
                    var seconds = _this.find(options.secondsSelector);
                    console.log(_this);
                    var currentSeconds=seconds.text();
                    currentSeconds--;
                    if(currentSeconds<0)
                    {
                        seconds.text("59");
                        var currentMinutes=minutes.text();
                        currentMinutes--;
                        if(currentMinutes<0)
                        {
                            (minutes).text("59");
                            var currentHours=(hours).text();
                            currentHours--;
                            if(currentHours<0)
                            {
                                (hours).text("23"); 
                                var currentDays=(hours).text();
                                currentDays--;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(currentHours.toString().length==1)
                                {
                                    (hours).text('0'+currentHours);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    (hours).text(currentHours);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(currentMinutes.toString().length==1)
                            {
                                (minutes).text('0'+currentMinutes);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                (minutes).text(currentMinutes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(currentSeconds.toString().length==1)
                        {
                            seconds.text('0'+currentSeconds);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            seconds.text(currentSeconds);
                        }
                    }   
                }

                return this.each(function() 
                {
                    console.log(_this);
                    setInterval("this.tick()",1000);
                });
            }
        });

        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#timer1").countdown();
            $("#timer2").countdown();
            $("#timer3").countdown();
        });

    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="timer1">
        <span class="days">1</span>
        <span class="hours">18</span>
        <span class="minutes">6</span>
        <span class="seconds">45</span>
    </div>

    <div id="timer2">
        <span class="days">2</span>
        <span class="hours">28</span>
        <span class="minutes">1</span>
        <span class="seconds">59</span>
    </div>

    <div id="timer3">
        <span class="days">10</span>
        <span class="hours">0</span>
        <span class="minutes">59</span>
        <span class="seconds">59</span>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code here?Stackoverflow doesn't rely on external service for his questions to be answered.

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code here

Comment: Please also have a look at my answer for some suggestions to improve your plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code

```
(function($){
            $.fn.extend({

                countdown: function(options) {

                var defaults = {
                    daysSelector : 'span.days',
                    hoursSelector : 'span.hours',
                    minutesSelector : 'span.minutes',
                    secondsSelector : 'span.seconds'
                }

                var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
                var _this  = $(this);

               var tick =  function()
                {
                    var    days = _this.find(options.daysSelector);
                    var    hours = _this.find(options.hoursSelector);
                    var    minutes = _this.find(options.minutesSelector);
                    var    seconds = _this.find(options.secondsSelector);
                    console.log(_this);
                    var currentSeconds=seconds.text();
                    currentSeconds--;
                    if(currentSeconds<0)
                    {
                        seconds.text("59");
                        var currentMinutes=minutes.text();
                        currentMinutes--;
                        if(currentMinutes<0)
                        {
                            (minutes).text("59");
                            var currentHours=(hours).text();
                            currentHours--;
                            if(currentHours<0)
                            {
                                (hours).text("23");    
                                var currentDays=(hours).text();
                                currentDays--;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(currentHours.toString().length==1)
                                {
                                    (hours).text('0'+currentHours);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    (hours).text(currentHours);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(currentMinutes.toString().length==1)
                            {
                                (minutes).text('0'+currentMinutes);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                (minutes).text(currentMinutes);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(currentSeconds.toString().length==1)
                        {
                            seconds.text('0'+currentSeconds);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            seconds.text(currentSeconds);
                        }
                    }    
                }

                return _this.each(function() 
                {
                    console.log(_this);
                    setInterval(tick,1000);
                });
            }
        });

        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#timer1").countdown();
            $("#timer2").countdown();
            $("#timer3").countdown();
        });
```

tick was global and that  was the problem (also never pass code to be evalued to setInterval!

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kvqWR/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I have to guess what the issue is... only 1 timer actually counts down and the other two doesn't?

That's because the extended countdown timer function you have never passes the name (id) of the countdown timer through to the function. So it always only executes the last one since the last one is what was called...last.

You'd need to send through the name (id) of the div for it to count down all 3 simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `tick` in global scope. Make it local:

```
var tick =  function()...
```

and don't pass a string to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(tick,1000);
```

---

A better structure of your plugin would be to declare the `tick` function only once and pass the current element (or the time fields) as argument:

```
(function($){
     var tick = function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
         //...
     };

     $.fn.countdown = function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                daysSelector : 'span.days',
                hoursSelector : 'span.hours',
                minutesSelector : 'span.minutes',
                secondsSelector : 'span.seconds'
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function(){
                var days = $(this).find(options.daysSelector);
                var hours = $(this).find(options.hoursSelector);
                var minutes = $(this).find(options.minutesSelector);
                var seconds = $(this).find(options.secondsSelector);
                setInterval(function() {
                    tick(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
                },1000);
            });
       };
}(jQuery));
```

Then your plugin also works if you select multiple elements at once:

```
$("#timer1, #timer2, #timer3").countdown();
```

which would **not work** otherwise (see here http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kvqWR/5/).

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kvqWR/3/)

It might also be better to have only `setInterval` going on which iterates over selected elements and performs the operation. The fewer timers you have, the better. Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kvqWR/4/